# What is the difference between AndEngine and LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, andengine

I read that they both are based in OpenGL ES 2 and both have Box2D physics.
I'm pretty new into Android game development, but somewhat experienced with game development (C++ and C#/XNA).  I also have experience with Unity and Construct2.

So, I'm trying to find a great game engine to use to develop 2D games.

Do you guys have any recommendations or anything?  I'm willing to purchase books and whatnot.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that LibGDX is a cross-platform framework.

You can basically write code just once and then deploy it with nearly no changes to desktop, Android, iOS, and even the browser via GWT/HTML 5. This is really convenient and will make debugging and developing in total a lot faster.

For more discussions like this see the following questions (make sure to read all answers and comments, since this is mostly an opinion based topic here).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669268/andengine-vs-libgdx?rq=1

[Switching from AndEngine to libgdx - what to know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465013/switching-from-andengine-to-libgdx-what-to-know?rq=1)

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43332/difference-between-libgdx-and-andengine

I am quite experienced with LibGDX and can definetely say it is a great framework with a really helpful and active community.

Comment: i can confirm that there is a create active community and also a good documentation. Alot of tutorials are out there and smaller issues get fast fixes with the nightly builds

Answer (score 1):

This question is not what SO is made for. Just to let you know, i think it will soon be closed.
Anyways: This 2 are 2 different engines. I am using `Libgdx` and have never used `AndEngine`. But i have read some discussions, so i list some of the differences:

1. AndEngine lets you start faster, Libgdx needs some setup and experience (IMHO)
2. Libgdx supports crossplatforming, meaning you can develop 99% on desktop and when you finished you can add a few codelines and it runs on Android to.
3. Libgdx is a bit more flexible and powerful, which is positiv and negativ (to flexible is overkill)
4. Libgdx has most times a better performance as much as i know.
5. Both have a 2D scenegraph and other possibilities to (low level ways)

Source: [AndEngine vs Libgdx](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/xR6e9JNpwWM), the developer talk both about their engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well [AndEngine](http://www.matim-dev.com/joints---introduction.html)is a native library for Android platform.But [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html) is a cross platform gaming library which can support all platforms.If you want to support your game to many platforms than use lidgdx.If you are targeting only for android then  AndEngine is good Solutions.Both have to code in Java only.
If you are good at C++, i recommend you to go for Cocos2dX which is also a Cross platform gaming library supporting all platforms.check this link for [cocos2dX](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Basic_Concepts)